# Check if filter value exists before applying filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to filter out specific records via a helper column and then copy/paste any of the filtered rows to another worksheet. The helper column returns either 0 (not applicable) or 1 (applicable), and the macro is supposed to copy all records that are flagged "1".

The problem is that in case I have no "1" records in the helper column, the macro copies all "0" (= all entries) to the new sheet, most likely because it cannot find any records with value "1".

How can I check whether the helper column has records with "1" before applying the filter? Preferably, if there are no records with "1", I skip the whole `with` and move on to the next step of the code.

```vb
With ThisWorkbook
    ' track last row for comment insert
    lastrow_fb = Sheets("Monthly Comments").Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    ' filter all records where helper column has value "1"
    .Sheets(DataYear & "_YTD").Range("SY2").AutoFilter Field:=519, Criteria1:="1"
    
    ' copy meta data
    .Sheets(DataYear & "_YTD").Range("F3:I" & lastrow).Copy
    .Sheets("Monthly Comments").Range("C" & lastrow_fb).PasteSpecial xlValues
    
    ' copy positive highlight
    .Sheets(DataYear & "_YTD").Range("CI3:CI" & lastrow).Copy
    .Sheets("Monthly Comments").Range("C" & lastrow_fb).Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial xlValues
    
    ' copy negative improvement suggestion
    .Sheets(DataYear & "_YTD").Range("CK3:CK" & lastrow).Copy
    .Sheets("Monthly Comments").Range("C" & lastrow_fb).Offset(0, 5).PasteSpecial xlValues
    
    ' write outlet name
    .Sheets("Monthly Comments").Range(Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1), Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1)).Value = "Name"
    
    ' unset helper column filter for next loop
    .Sheets(DataYear & "_YTD").Range("SY2").AutoFilter Field:=519
End With
```

Comment: how do you assign the `lastrow` value? I mean the one used in `.Sheets(DataYear & "_YTD").Range("F3:I" & lastrow).Copy` not the `lastrow_fb`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to determine the number and/or presence of filtered elements in a filter range. Below are some of them

```
Sub CheckFilter()
    Dim af As AutoFilter, filter_body_range As Range, rng_to_copy As Range
    
    Set af = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).AutoFilter
    Set filter_body_range = Intersect(af.Range, af.Range.Offset(1))
    
    ' option 1
    Set rng_to_copy = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng_to_copy = filter_body_range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng_to_copy Is Nothing Then
        rng_to_copy.Copy
        Debug.Print "Visible rows in the filter range has been copied: address " & rng_to_copy.Address
        ' paste to the target place
    End If
    
    'option 2
    m = Application.Match(1, filter_body_range.Columns(5), 0)
    If IsNumeric(m) Then
        Debug.Print "The 5 column has value 1"
        ' your code to copy/paste
    End If
    
    ' option 3
    filtered_rows = 0
    On Error Resume Next ' switch off system error handling: if no xlCellTypeVisible cells, error occurs
    filtered_rows = filter_body_range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    On Error GoTo 0 'switch on system error handling
    If filtered_rows > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Filtered range has " & filtered_rows & " visible rows"
        ' your code to copy/paste
    End If
End Sub
```

Prints:

```
Visible rows in the filter range has been copied: address $C$7:$L$7,$C$13:$L$17,$C$24:$L$26
The 5 column has value 1
Filtered range has 9 visible rows
```

[image]